# How to delete a feature branch in Gitlab? Standard gitlab-ce image, running in Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab

When I try to delete an old feature branch like `feature/xyz` in Gitlab web UI, the answer is a red error message `Something went wrong on our end.`
Looks like it is an old Gitlab problem with branch names containing slashes:

- [gitlab-foss #1804](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/1804) Deleting branches doesn't work for branch names containing slashes (/)
- [gitlab-foss #1399](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/1399) Compare-View is broken when branch name contains slash ("/")

My Gitlab runs in Docker - gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest (12.9.2)
Do you have the same problem with the gitlab-ce docker image? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the issue was not in the Gitlab image itself, but in the Apache VirtualHost proxying to the docker image. So I did not have to change anything in the gitlab-ce docker image, just adding the following line to the Apache VirtualHost in front of Docker: `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode`

The idea came from [gitlab-foss #1399](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/1399)